# How do i get the most updated api by android?

Tags: android, api, casting, findviewbyid

I would like to use the "new" findViewById that returns **T extends View** and not just **View** , what do i need to update to receive that ?

this is the updated Doc :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

the new method  is already there .

Comment: you have to target version of android (currently in beta stage so you cannot release an app with it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install [Android Studio 3.0 Preview/Canary](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html) and update all required SDK/Tools.

You have to Target the new API-Level, e.g.:

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 'android-O'
   buildToolsVersion '26.0.0-rc2'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 'O'
        ....
    }
}
```

Note that the Preview is only available from the Google Maven Repository, e.g.:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is only available on Android O and higher. Presently, there are zero production devices that run Android O.

Sometime later in 2017, Android O will ship. Let's presume that it is API Level 26. At that time, if you set `compileSdkVersion` to 26, you can compile code that references that version of `findViewById()`. However, that code will *only* run on API Level 26+ devices, which means that you need to set your `minSdkVersion` to 26 or avoid executing that code on older devices.

If you want to experiment with this today, you can set your `compileSdkVersion` to `android-O`. However, the resulting app will *only* run on devices or emulators with the O Developer Preview on it.

Comment: i do want to experiment...but how to i set the api level to 26 ? it required download that not available yet .

Comment: @JesusDimrix: "but how to i set the api level to 26 ?" -- that is not possible today. If you read the third paragraph of my answer, I point out what you can do today (use `android-O`).